# enable disable option of console output in multithreaded applications

Tags: c#, console-application, server-application

Hello I am working on a Server Application that is multithreaded having a control panel form and a console for the output. I am using log by console output. For Enabling log I compile the version with log and for disabling log I compile the version without log. This is handled as I use all code is between the lines.

```
#if Enable_DEBUG_ECHO
Console.WriteLine("Something is happening");
#endif
```

so I if use `#define Enable_DEBUG_ECHO` on top of file it compiles for echo. But I want implement a option by which user can enable/disable log by single click or something like that. Somebody give me the idea how can I do this.

Comment: `bool logEnabled = true/false` then `if(logEnabled)...`

Comment: Take a look at [`log4net`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4net/) library.

Answer (score 2):

You know, when u are using precompile options (such as your code), the program contains only code one 'version' of code (I mean, that if you define Enable_DEBUG_ECHO, line 'Console.WriteLine("Something is happening");' will included in result dll, but it will not included if you don't define Enable_DEBUG_ECHO).

So if u want to enable/disable your log in runtime, u should create your log without precompile options.

So u need to save your 'turn on/off' variable in configuration file. And than

```
if (VARIABLE_FROM_CONFIG)
{
Console.WriteLine("Something is happening");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logging framework such as [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [log4net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4net/), that makes all this so easy. You can configure them programatically or through configuration files.